# Accessing a webcam with Python 3.X

Tags: python, webcam

For a school project I am using a Raspberry Pi to detect certain colours in a webcam image. However, I can't seem to find any way to access the webcam using Python 3.X. Are there any libraries out there that work with python 3.X that work for both windows and linux (I'm creating the program on windows 7 but going to be using it on the R-Pi)?

If not, I suppose I could end up settling for Python 2.7 simply because the R-Pi has both versions installed on it (Although I don't know 2.7 so it may not go too well).

Comment: Take a look at http://opencv.org/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this:

1. You can use [OpenCV](http://code.google.com/p/ctypes-opencv/) which has support for getting data from a webcam and there are Python wrappers for it;
2. [gstreamer](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/webcam-viewer.html) has python bindings too;

Also, on GNU/Linux, you can use [v4l2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/v4l2).